# Determine the matrix $L$ with respect to a basis of eigenvectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let $V = R[X]_{≤3}$ and $α ∈ R$. Define the linear image $ L : V → V$
given by $L(P(X)) = αP(X) + (X + 1)P'(X)$.

Proof that $L$ diagonalizable and determine the matrix $L$ with respect to a basis of eigenvectors.

I have found this matrix:

$$L=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&1&0&0\\\ 0&1+\alpha&2&0\\0&0&2+\alpha&3\\0&0&0&3+\alpha\end{bmatrix}.$$
I used the standard basis {${1,x,x^2,x^3}$}

Then you know the eigenvalues are $\alpha, 1+\alpha, 2+\alpha$ and $3+\alpha$ with respectively the eigenspaces $(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)$ and because every $d(\lambda)=m(\lambda)$ we know that $L$ is diagonalizable.

First is this correct? If so, How do I construct the matrix $L$ with respect to a basis of eigenvectors.
Is it possible that this is just the matrix with on the diagonal the eigenvalues?

Comment: The matrix in the standard basis is correct. You deduce indeed, because it is triangular, that the eigenvalues are $\alpha$, $1+\alpha$,  $2+\alpha$ and  $3+\alpha$. They are all disctincts, so the matrix is diagonalizable. But you are wrong about the eigenspaces : the vectors of the standard basis are not eigenvectors, otherwise the matrix would be diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try and find the eigenvectors *of the representing matrix* with respect to $\alpha$. We need to find the null space of
$$
L-\alpha I=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0&0\\
0&1&2&0\\
0&0&2&3\\
0&0&0&3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and we find $[1\ 0\ 0\ 0]^T$. This yields the polynomial $1$ as an eigenvector for $L$.

With respect to $1+\alpha$, we need the null space of
$$
L-(1+\alpha) I=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&1&0&0\\
0&0&2&0\\
0&0&1&3\\
0&0&0&2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and we find $[1\ 1\ 0\ 0]^T$. This yields $1+x$ as an eigenvector for $L$.

You may find also the other eigenvectors. However, you don't need it. The matrix with respect to a basis of eigenvectors is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1+\alpha & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2+\alpha & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3+\alpha
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(or any permutation of the eigenvalues along the diagonal).